# Convert Multiple Choice Data to Numeric

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
+-------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|   gender    |    age     |      income      | ate_string_cheese | tech_familiarity |
+-------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| A. Female   | D. 45-54   | B. $50K - $80K   | B. Once or twice  | A. Low           |
| A. Female   | C. 35-44   | A. $35K - $49K   | B. Once or twice  | B. Medium        |
| B. Male     | B. 25-34   | B. 50k - 79,999  | B. Once or twice  | C. High          |
| A. Female   | A. 18-24   | D. $100k - $149k | B. Once or twice  | B. Medium        |
+-------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

I want to try to find correlations between different observations. I need the values to be numerical. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do this in R?

To be clear the result from above would look like this:

```
+--------+-----+--------+-------------------+------------------+
| gender | age | income | ate_string_cheese | tech_familiarity |
+--------+-----+--------+-------------------+------------------+
|      1 |   4 |      2 |                 2 |                1 |
|      1 |   3 |      1 |                 2 |                2 |
|      2 |   2 |      2 |                 2 |                3 |
|      1 |   1 |      4 |                 2 |                2 |
+--------+-----+--------+-------------------+------------------+
```

I'm assuming there must be a package for this, but I can't find the Google incantation that will conjure it. Please know that I'm a complete statistic newbie who's just poking around. So if you prod me for more details, I likely won't have an educated answer to return.

Comment: Try by converting to `factor` and coerce it to `integer` `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.integer(factor(x)))`  specify the levels if you need in  a particular order

Comment: the `ate_string_cheese` have only one unique value.  why is it starting at 2 instead of 1

Comment: @akrun, great question! It's an incomplete data set (also made up, but I got lazy inventing it).

Comment: Any feedback on why this question was down voted? I put forth effort in searching for a solution before posting, didn't find an answer. I provided context, and relevant data. What's the trouble?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the feedback @akrun. I struggle getting tabular data to look right and make it easy to work with on here.

Comment: I thought it was from SAS format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about converting categorical data into numerical data in R:

You can convert character data into `factor`  using `as.factor()`

> factor returns an object of class "factor" which has a set of integer codes the length of x with a "levels" attribute of mode character.

Pros:

- This will encode your data numerically with an attribute that maps the character value for reference.
- Factors can be ordered which can capture important information about ordinal data (such as age bands in your case)

Cons:

- Beware converting categorical data into numeric for the purposes of performing statistical analysis on the data. The numerical values are probably not on the interval or ratio scale for all questions, so taking things like the mean or difference between levels may not make sense. e.g. consider if the distance between each level is actually constant, does it have a natural zero point etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I completely forgot about factors—of course! One of those cases where the answer was so obvious you won't find it by searching. :bows to the master:

Answer (score 1):

You need to just extract first character, convert it to lowercase and map it with number:

```
# Your original data frame 
df=read.table(text="gender;age;income;ate_string_cheese;tech_familiarity
A. Female;D.45-54;B.$50K - $80K;B.Once or twice;A.Low
A. Female;C.35-44;A.$35K - $49K;B.Once or twice;B. Medium 
B. Male;B.25-34;B.50k - 79,999;B.Once or twice;C. High 
A. Female;A. 18-24;D.$100k - $149k;B.Once or twice;B. Medium",header=T,sep=";")

myLetters <- letters[1:26]
# Apply match function to df, convert to lowercase and map it with number 
sapply(df, function(x) match(tolower(gsub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", x)), myLetters))
```

Output:

```
      gender age income ate_string_cheese tech_familiarity
[1,]      1   4      2                 2                1
[2,]      1   3      1                 2                2
[3,]      2   2      2                 2                3
[4,]      1   1      4                 2                2
```

Comment: Why are you creating `myLetters` and using `tolower` when `LETTERS` is available? I'd just do `df[] <- match(substr(trimws(unlist(df, use.names = FALSE)), 1, 1), LETTERS); df`.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1: Thanks for correcting me. Your approach is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could trim the whitepace, and just grab the `A,B,C,D` parts and call `factor` on each column with `level=LETTERS[1:4]` and `labels=1:4`.

```
 structure(factor(sub('\\..*','',trimws(as.matrix(df))),labels=1:4),.Dim=dim(df),dimnames=dimnames(df))

  gender age income ate_string_cheese tech_familiarity
1 1      4   2      2                 1               
2 1      3   1      2                 2               
3 2      2   2      2                 3               
4 1      1   4      2                 2
```

This is a matrix. You can convert to a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the columns to `factor` and coerce it to `numeric`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.integer(factor(x)))
```